# Why do we detrend time series data?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, autoregressive, trend

If I have annual international trade (from 2000 to 2022) data and Country A has implemented a new policy in 2012. What is the benefit of detrending in this case if I want to investigate the impact of this new policy on trade?

Comment: How would you detrend it?

Comment: Since it is not true that you always need to detrend time-series data, could you be more specific on what do you mean?

Comment: This is a chicken-and-egg question. In very broad terms, the reasons for detrending range from technical (a method or model assumes trend-free data, so subtracting trend first is needed) to substantive (a natural or at least congenial way to think about a time series is as some combination such as trend, seasonality and noise).  It is often best to estimate trend at the same time as other components.

Comment: I have annual data, so I have no other option rather than moving the average. I just need to examine the impact of policy implemented in 2012